# SQL Query help: Getting counts based on combination of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (variable (unlimited variety), attr (exactly 3 different attributes), date, state (can only be 1,2, or 3) ):

```
 ------------------------------------
| Variable | Attr |   Date   | State |
|------------------------------------|
|    V1    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V1    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  2    |      
|    V1    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V1    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V1    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  1    |  
|    V1    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V1    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V1    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  2    |  
|    V2    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  2    |      
|    V2    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  1    |           
|    V2    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V2    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V2    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V2    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  0    |  
|    V2    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V2    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V2    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V2    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  1    |  
|    V3    |  A1  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A1  |01/02/14  |  2    |           
|    V3    |  A1  |01/03/14  |  1    |     
|    V3    |  A1  |01/04/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A2  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A2  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V3    |  A2  |01/03/14  |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A2  |01/04/14  |  2    |  
|    V3    |  A3  |01/01/14  |  1    |      
|    V3    |  A3  |01/02/14  |  0    |           
|    V3    |  A3  |01/03/14  |  2    |     
|    V1    |  A3  |01/04/14  |  1    | 
|    .     |  .   |.         |  .    |
|    Vn    |  An  |n         |  n    | 
|----------|------|----------|-------|
```

The output I want (note count is completely random values for this example):

```
 ------------------------------------
| Variable | Attr |   Count  | State |
 ------------------------------------
|    V1    |  A1  | 50   |  0    |      
|    V1    |  A1  | 24   |  1    | 
|    V1    |  A1  | 22   |  2    |                
|    V1    |  A2  | 1    |  0    |       
|    V1    |  A2  | 0    |  1    |
|    V1    |  A2  | 15   |  2    |      
|    V1    |  A3  | 68   |  0    |
|    V1    |  A3  | 9    |  1    | 
|    V1    |  A3  | 34   |  2    |       
|    V2    |  A1  | 10   |  0    |               
|    V2    |  A1  | 0    |  1    |
|    V2    |  A1  | 25   |  2    |                   
|    V2    |  A2  | 48   |  0    |     
|    V2    |  A2  | 96   |  1    | 
|    V2    |  A2  | 14   |  2    |             
|    V2    |  A3  | 12   |  0    |     
|    V2    |  A3  | 3    |  1    |
|    V2    |  A3  | 0    |  2    |              
|    V3    |  A1  | 4    |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A1  | 5    |  1    |
|    V3    |  A1  | 8    |  2    |                     
|    V3    |  A2  | 19   |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A2  | 95   |  1    | 
|    V3    |  A2  | 26   |  2    |                   
|    V3    |  A3  | 4    |  0    |     
|    V3    |  A3  | 85   |  1    |
|    V3    |  A3  | 50   |  2    |   
|    .     |  .   |.     |  .    |
|    Vn    |  An  |n     |  n    | 
|----------|------|------|-------|
```

The first thing I want to do is to choose a variable + attr + state combination which I want top base my query off of. So lets say I choose V2 + A3 + 2. Next I want to go and find the dates of all rows where var = V2, attr = A3, and state = 2. Next I need to go through each of these dates and count all the other var + attr + state combinations. For example if V2 + A3 + 2 occurs on 01/01/14, 02/06/14, 02/07/14, 04/09/14, and 05/03/14 it would go through all the other variables on these dates and add up the occurrences for each var + attr + state combination. So the output would group each var + attr + state combination and the count for each of these combinations would show.

I have tried numerous different thing such as left joins, inner joins

(e.g

```
SELECT variable, attr, count(state), state (SELECT variable, attr, state FROM t1 WHERE variable ='V2' AND Attr ='A3' and state = 2) a INNER JOIN t1 V on key a.date = b.date GROUP BY variable, attr
```

)

but can't get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  m2.variable, m2.attr, m2.state, COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable m1
JOIN    mytable m2
ON      m2.date = m1.date
WHERE   (m1.variable, m1.attr, m1.state) = ('V2', 'A3', 2)
GROUP BY
        m2.variable, m2.attr, m2.state
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I already tried this! I guess not, so simple thanks so much!